# Visualising PosgreSQL database raster table in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, postgis, postgresql, arcgis-pro

I have created a PostGIS-enabled PostgreSQL database, with a raster table in the public schema.

When I create a connection from ArcGIS Pro onto to that database, I can see the raster table but I can't seem to render the raster dataset.

Instead, all I can see is the raster table (imported as an standalone table).

Does ArcGIS Pro 3.X support PostgreSQL/PostGIS rasters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/474385/is-it-possible-to-visualise-a-posgresql-database-raster-table-in-arcgis-pro-3-x#comment774717_474385):

> No, there is no support for native PostGIS rasters from ArcGIS Pro.

At [PostgreSQL data types supported in ArcGIS](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/data/geodatabases/manage-postgresql/data-types-postgresql.htm) it says that:

> Rasters are supported only in geodatabases.